# Excel difference between cells in two tables

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I want to compare two tables in Excel 2010, and see the differences in the numeric cells in a third table?

Here is an example of the initial tables:

```
table 1
name    value   category
aa      1.0     red

table 2
name    category value
bb      blue     1.0
```

Comment: Please give a better more exact description of what you mean by `reconcile`.

Answer (score 1):

The caveats for this formula are

- tables are named ranges, *table1* and *table2*
- destination column has label in Row 1, values starting in Row 2

You'll have to modify the ROW() part based on your actual placement.  You can place it any way you want, you just have to change the ROW() part to give numbers starting at 2 and incrementing by 1.

```
=HLOOKUP("value",table1,ROW(),FALSE)-HLOOKUP("value",table2,ROW(),FALSE)
```

If you don't want zero value differences to show, you can either set the workbook to not show zeroes or mod the formula this way:

```
=IF(HLOOKUP("value",table1,ROW(),FALSE)-HLOOKUP("value",table2,ROW(),FALSE) > 0,
    HLOOKUP("value",table1,ROW(),FALSE)-HLOOKUP("value",table2,ROW(),FALSE),"")
```

Comment: The columns are switched and I would like to see the difference between numbers with a specified difference of 10E^-9 for example.